# jQuery calculate width, and apply width to desired container

Tags: jquery, width

I am attempting to calculate the viewport width, and then subtract a value from that then apply the result to the desired container. I've found some examples that are close and managed to cobble together the following but it's not doing any thing at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var aa = $(window).width(); 
var bb = $(“#controlWidget”).width();
var cc = (aa – bb) + "px";
document.getElementById(‘thumbList’).style.width = cc;
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

```
$(function() {
    $("#thumbList").width($(window).width() - $("#controlWidget").width());
});
```

Unless you're using them for something else, the temp variables are not needed.

Also, I have no idea if this is due to whatever editor you're using, but you've inserted invalid characters into your sample code block. For example, `“` should be `"` and `–` should be `-` (notice the subtle differences in both). Javascript interpreters bork on those characters as they're invalid in the given context.

Finally, you shouldn't mix pure Javascript with jQuery, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Rather than applying the width through `document.getElementById`, you should simply use jQuery's `width` function, which also allows you to set the width.

Comment: True Awesomeness, thanks. I actually just ended up swapping the controlWidget with the integer 260 and it works a charm, I did have another addition to the equation though, is there a simple way to make it recalculate on viewport re-size?

Answer (score 1):

1. check the value of aa and bb before last statement (use an alert or a console.log() )
2. be sure element `thumbList` exists
3. change last statement with a simpler `$(#thumbList).width(aa-bb)`

jQuery `width` can also be used to set a width, from http://api.jquery.com/width/

> If no explicit unit was specified (like 'em' or '%') then "px" is concatenated to the value.